# Calculate stats by userid, month, sum - select number of month in columns

Tags: mysql

I have table user_payments with columns

```
user_id / payment_date / type_payment / sum
111     /  2018-01-12   / card        / 131
111     /  2018-02-17   /  cash       /  18
124     /  2018-03-21   / card        /  148
119     /  2018-04-01   / card        /  225
```

i need to transform it like this by query

```
user_id / 1 (month_numb) type_pay / sum(sum of 1st month) / 2 / 2_sum
111    /  card                    / 131                  / cash/ 18
```

Comment: What should happen if someone pays by card and cash in the same month?

Comment: Should the first month of 2017 be added to the first month of 2018? Or will the table only ever contain data for one year?

Comment: Is the number of months static or do you want dynamic number of months?

Comment: add another raw with current user_id

Comment: it will by query for one year

Comment: it will be static, i will grab them like mont(date) and if user have no payments in 3rd month, for example, i had to write null in two columns of 3rd month type and 3rd month summ

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0):

As what I understand you have:
year, month, type, and sum,
Since all of these data are dynamic in row level.  This is what i come up with.

```
SELECT p.user_id, YEAR(payment_date), MONTH(payment_date), type_payment, SUM(p.`sum`)
FROM user_payments as p
group by p.user_id, YEAR(payment_date), MONTH(payment_date), type_payment
ORDER BY p.user_id, YEAR(payment_date), MONTH(payment_date), type_payment
```

Generating columns dynamically might be a hassle.

What if the the user 111 has 6 payments in one month (considering there are other types). Does it mean have to generate more columns to satisfy the 6 records?
Having dynamic columns might be difficult in programming aspect.

Comment: I need maybe transpose it, because like i write in expected result from query - i need number of month in columns and result should be like 

id  //   1 (number of month) payment type ///  sum of 1st month // 2 payment /// sum of 2nd